# Using USB keyboard on Dell U2514/MacBook Pro

Tags: macos, external-display, displayport

I recently got a Dell U2415 monitor that I'm using with my MacBook Pro (2014). I want something I thought was simple: using a USB keyboard that's plugged in to the monitor's USB port.

The monitor is connected using (mini) DisplayPort. From sources online it sounds like DisplayPort 1.2 is required to carry USB over DisplayPort. When I enable DP 1.2 on my monitor, the monitor goes blank. Before enabling, the monitor warns me that a blank screen will happen if the graphics card doesn't support it. According to this [page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202856), my laptop has DP 1.2.

Furthermore, graphical issues aside, the keyboard still doesn't work even after enabling DP 1.2 on the monitor.

It seems like something so basic should be possible. Apple's Thunderbolt Display from 2011 can do it, Dell claims their monitor supports it, yet I can't get it work. FWIW, I'm running OS X 10.11. Anybody have a clue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If its the same as other Dell monitors you'd still need to connect the monitor's USB type B port to the system for the onboard ports to work. AFAICT there's no provision for carrying usb over mini DP on any dell I've seen.

Comment: correct.  the usb hub in the monitor is not connected to DisplayPort of the monitor in any way.  The only thing the usb hub and the monitor share is power.

Comment: Thanks, that's disappointing as it means I'll always have to plug in 2 cables when I want to use my laptop with the monitor. Was hoping to avoid that, but alas. First world problem, I guess :) Do you have an explanation for the blank screen when enabling DP 1.2 on the monitor?

Comment: Alas no. My hardware works perfectly fine, but its a p2715Q and a desktop with a 980TI - so I'm pretty certain I'm running DP1.2 with no issues. That said, at your current resolution you don't need DP 1.2, unless you intend to daisychain. I'm also speculating if the mini dp port won't support 1.2 but that would be *strange*.

Comment: I'm using mini DP only on the MacBook side, it's regular DP on the monitor side so all should be good. But like you said, I don't really need it so it doesn't really matter. I appreciate your help!